# Django formset duplicate values

Tags: python, django, django-forms, duplicates

I'm dynamically creating more forms under Django templates with jQuery.formsets. The problem is that I get duplicate values entered to the database.

As far as I can tell the IDs generated by jQuery.formsets are correct because when I print out request.POST under views it displays the correct values.

The values in question are 'Observer ONE/TWO/THREE' with the following IDs before clicking submit:

- id_form-0-observed_by_0
- form-1-id_form-0-observed_by_0
- form-2-id_form-0-observed_by_0

request.POST:

```
<QueryDict: {u'form-1-form-INITIAL_FORMS': [u''], u'form-1-form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u''], u'commune': [u'Tartu'], u'additional_workgroups_view_0': [u''], u'form-0-observed_by_1': [u'3'], u'form-0-observed_by_0': [u'Observer ONE'], u'sample': [u''], u'remarks': [u''], u'access_edit': [u'private'], u'district': [u'Tartu'], u'country_1': [u'EE'], u'access_view': [u'public'], u'form-2-form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u''], u'substrate_1': [u''], u'substrate_0': [u''], u'geom': [u''], u'exact_date_and_time': [u''], u'latitude': [u'25.36698180'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'AJTXFtEYQbX0pdBdvSe53443HKHN5dvg'], u'method': [u'MAP'], u'coordinate_uncertainty_in_meters': [u'200'], u'form-1-form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u''], u'elevation': [u''], u'country_0': [u'Estonia'], u'timespan_begin': [u'25-03-2013 11:08'], u'locality_text': [u'Ravila 19'], u'additional_users_view_0': [u''], u'timespan_end': [u''], u'form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'3'], u'form-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'0'], u'form-2-form-INITIAL_FORMS': [u''], u'taxon_node_0': [u'Fungi'], u'taxon_node_1': [u'5'], u'district_ehak': [u''], u'form-2-observed_by_1': [u'3'], u'form-2-observed_by_0': [u'Observer THREE'], u'form-1-observed_by_0': [u'Observer TWO'], u'form-1-observed_by_1': [u'1'], u'form-2-form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u''], u'commune_ehak': [u''], u'additional_users_edit_0': [u''], u'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u''], u'study': [u'2'], u'longitude': [u'15.69302410'], u'additional_workgroups_edit_0': [u''], u'remarks_sample': [u''], u'kingdom_helper': [u'5']}>
```

However, when I print out the formset itself the form0 and form2 values seem to be duplicated.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="3" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" />
<input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" />
<input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS"/>
<tr>
    <th>
        <label for="id_form-0-observed_by_0"></label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input style="width: 200px" name="form-0-observed_by_0" required="True" value="Observer THREE" id="id_form-0-observed_by_0" data-selectable-type="text" data-selectable-allow-new="false" data-selectable-url="/selectable/agent-personlookup/" type="text" class="span12"/>
        <input data-selectable-type="hidden" name="form-0-observed_by_1" id="id_form-0-observed_by_1" required="True" type="hidden" style="width: 200px" value="3" class="span12" />
    </td>
    </tr> 
<tr>
    <th>
        <label for="id_form-1-observed_by_0"></label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input style="width: 200px" name="form-1-observed_by_0" required="True" value="Observer ONE" id="id_form-1-observed_by_0" data-selectable-type="text" data-selectable-allow-new="false" data-selectable-url="/selectable/agent-personlookup/" type="text" class="span12"/>
        <input data-selectable-type="hidden" name="form-1-observed_by_1" id="id_form-1-observed_by_1" required="True" type="hidden" style="width: 200px" value="1" class="span12"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        <label for="id_form-2-observed_by_0"></label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input style="width: 200px" name="form-2-observed_by_0" required="True" value="Observer THREE" id="id_form-2-observed_by_0" data-selectable-type="text" data-selectable-allow-new="false" data-selectable-url="/selectable/agent-personlookup/" type="text" class="span12"/>
        <input data-selectable-type="hidden" name="form-2-observed_by_1" id="id_form-2-observed_by_1" required="True" type="hidden" style="width: 200px" value="3" class="span12"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

View:

```
def observation_add(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    print 'REQUEST POST START'
    print request.POST
    print 'REQUEST POST END'
    ObservedByFormset = formset_factory(ObservedByForm)
    observed_by_formset = ObservedByFormset(request.POST)
    print 'DEBUG: FORM BEFORE VALID:', observed_by_formset
```

Comment: We need to see your view code.

Comment: But that's not putting anything into the database. Where's the code that does that?

Comment: That code is irrelevant since when I print out my formset before is_valid() I'm already getting the wrong values. I do however get the correct values when I print out request.POST

Comment: How are you rendering the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was jquery.dj.selectable.js that was changing hidden fields value and therefore messing up the backend. The script had to be placed exactly in between the form div and for loop.

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/selectable/js/jquery.dj.selectable.js"></script>
<div id="table_rel">
```